# React app hangs and uses 300% CPU when going to a page

Tags: reactjs

I just added a sign in page and component to an example react app I'm working on, but any time I navigate to the new page (`localhost:3000/signin`), the page hangs and looking into the Chrome task manager, starts using 300+% CPU power.  Nothing is printed to the console, and nothing ever shows up on the screen.

I know this can happen when there is some sort of call loop that tries to render infinitely, but I don't see where that could be happening in the code I have.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

import HomePage from "./pages/homepage/homepage";
import ShopPage from "./pages/shop/shopPage";
import Header from "./components/header/header";
import SignInAndSignUpPage from "./pages/signInSignUp/signInSignUp";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignInAndSignUpPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my SignIn/SignUp page (sign up not implemented yet):

```
import React from "react";

import SignIn from "../signInSignUp/signInSignUp";

import "./signInSignUp.scss";

const SignInAndSignUpPage = () => (
  <div className="sign-in-and-sign-up">
    <SignIn />
  </div>
);

export default SignInAndSignUpPage;
```

and my SignIn component:

```
import React from "react";

import "./sign-in.styles.scss";

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ email: "", password: "" });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sign-in">
        <h2>I already have an account</h2>
        <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="email"
            type="email"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.email}
            label="email"
            required
          />
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            label="password"
            required
          />
          <input type="submit"> Sign in </input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend debugging by commenting sections out until it doesn't exhibit the bad behavior. Then gradually reintroduce fragments of code/markup.

Comment: only thing that stands out to me is `<input type="submit"> Sign in </input>` Should  be self-closing with a `value` attribute instead

Comment: @jarmod I did that, and was able to reduce the SignIn component down to just an h1 tag and it still exhibited the behavior

Comment: what happens if you don't render the <SignIn /> component at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this issue was caused by a recursive import in another file.  The component was importing itself by mistake, which caused infinite re-rendering.  Always double-check your imports!